# How to convert 32 bit mantissa (IEEE754) to decimal number using Java?

Tags: java, ieee-754

I have this for example:

> 0 10000101 00111100000000000000000

and want to convert this to decimal number.

So far, I already have the code to get the exponent part:

```
String[]hex={"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","A","B","C","D","E","F"};
 String[]binary={"0000","0001","0010","0011","0100","0101","0110","0111","1000","1001","1010","1011","1100","1101","1110","1111"};

String userInput="429E0000";
 String result="";
 for(int i=0;i<userInput.length();i++)
 {
  char temp=userInput.charAt(i);
  String temp2=""+temp+"";
  for(int j=0;j<hex.length;j++)
  {
   if(temp2.equalsIgnoreCase(hex[j]))
   {
    result=result+binary[j];
   }
  }
 }
 System.out.println(result);

    int exponent = Integer.parseInt(result.substring(1,9),2)-127;
    System.out.println(exponent);
```

Is there any in-built command in Java?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, there is a built-in command, [intBitsToFloat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#intBitsToFloat%28int%29) converts a 32-bit `int` to a `float`. You only have to parse your input as an `int`, the easier way - if your input is in hexadecimal format - would be to directly use base 16 in `Integer.parseInt()`, then `intBitsToFloat` converts that bit pattern to a `float`.

Answer (score 2):

The [`Integer.ParseInteger(str, radix)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) will convert a binary digit string to an `int` ... if you use two as the radix.

However, Daniels answer gives you a better approach that avoids the need for any intermediate string representation of the number.